# angular ternary operator in view issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need help understanding why this angular ternary doesn't work right

```
ng-mouseleave="window.location.href.indexOf('sell') != -1 ? sellModal = true : newsletterModal = true"
```

I want to set either sellModal or newsletterModal to true based on the url, however only the if condition works correctly and if the user is on the sell page then sellModal pops up, if they are on another page the newsletterModal is not set to true and this doesn't work.

Comment: Sounds like the issue isn't with your ternary operator but rather your newsletterModal, since it works in one case but not the other.

Comment: I made sure both modals work by setting them manually to true in the ng-mouseleave.

Comment: Don't overuse such angular expressions. It makes code changes hard to implement, and also hard to read. Do your future self a favor and extract such behavior to a controller method or similar.

Comment: why are you parsing the url in the view? You have path information available in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not overkill the html, just make a function

```
$scope.onLeave = function(){
    if (window.location.href.indexOf('sell') != -1) {
        $scope.sellModal = true;
    } else {
        $scope.newsletterModal = true;
    }
}
```

And then in your html...

```
ng-mouseleave="onLeave"
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a function but it looks like there is no other option. thanks!